# How do I populate html tables with ruby code?

Tags: html, ruby, html-table

I am really new to Ruby programming and am in the process of trying to learn it. one of the "assignments" I was given is really stumping me.
I need to make a table with 2 columns. the first column will have a list of numbers 1 through 100,
the second column will print out the results as per my code.

My ruby code looks like this:

```
 (1..100).each do |i|
  d3 = (i % 3 == 0) 
  d5 = (i % 5 == 0)

  i = "_#{i}_" if d5
  i = "*#{i}*" if d3

  puts i if d5 || d3
end
```

How would I put this in an HTML table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if your using rails or not, but you'll need to make sure it using erb [this might help](http://www.stuartellis.eu/articles/erb/).  But something like this should do the trick:

```
   <table>
    <%  (1..100).each_with_index do |n| 
      d3 = (i % 3 == 0) 
      d5 = (i % 5 == 0)

      i = "_#{i}_" if d5
      i = "*#{i}*" if d3 %>

      <tr>
       <td><%= n %></td>
       <td><%= i if d5 || d3 %>
    <% end %>
    <table>
```